# Performance issue with local dev environment

Tags: microservices, development-environment

I have a large project with large set of micro-services. When I am working locally my computer barely handles running all of them plus IDE, MySQL and Mongo. This inconvenience is blocking me to add more micro-services.
Is there a known practice to work in this kind of environment?

Comment: Test environment in the cloud would be one way to go.

Comment: Cloud sounds interesting! But I need a dev environment and not a testing env, where I can debug the microservice I'm working on with my IDE.

Comment: Distributed systems come with their own issues when it comes to debugging and you'll need special frameworks, for example https://github.com/solo-io/squash

Comment: Awesome! That looks great. I will take a look into it.